# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden when post xml data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting the error

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

when post some xml data to a api. Below is the code.
I have read some other questions from stack overflow but doesn't fix.

```
public static XmlDocument PlaceOrder(string Url, string Method, string payload)
{

    Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
    HttpWebRequest apiCall = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);

    byte[] byteArray = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    apiCall.Accept = "*/*";
    apiCall.KeepAlive = false;
    apiCall.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    apiCall.Method = "POST";
    apiCall.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    apiCall.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    apiCall.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36";
    apiCall.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    apiCall.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    apiCall.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    apiCall.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    apiCall.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    Stream dataStream = apiCall.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse webresponse;
    webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)apiCall.GetResponse();

    StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
    string response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

    XmlDocument toReturn = new XmlDocument();
    toReturn.LoadXml(response);

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: This might happend when your ip is blocked by the server. So try from another location

Comment: I have tried this from 3 different locations.

Comment: Find details about this error in the api documentation near the type of post you are doing

Comment: Which server do you post to? Try getting to its logs if it's under your control, if it's not request from the team supporting that

Comment: Thanks Ivan, Its a third party Api , and I can Successfully submit my data using DHC rest client.